# Ubuntu 20 application menu scrolling issue

Tags: crash, appmenu, scrolling, linux-headers, scrollbar

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS , everything seemed to function normally initially for 2 days.

But now the application menu is stuck, and i cant scroll there. Although I can access any application from the menu (those which are visible), other which I can't access because I can't scroll them.

The apps are accessible via application search. Scrolling is working perfectly everywhere except for the application menu. The option of 'all apps', next to  'frequent', starts shaking as soon as its selected.

Has anyone had this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing same issue.
Did you change shell theme in "Gnome Tweaks"?

Try changing theme of shell.

Go to **Tweaks > Appearance > Shell** and select *Yaru-dark*.

This worked for me.

Comment: thanks man, you're right.it was the tweaks , everything worked fine after i changed them to default.